# NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.ca/QuietComfort-Wireless-Headphones-Cancelling-Control/dp/B0756CYWWD/ref=sr_1_3?crid=11Q0SFC2UP92R&keywords=bose+quietcomfort+35&qid=1588098577&s=electronics&sprefix=bose+q%2Celectronics%2C160&sr=1-3'
r = requests.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
original_price = soup.find(id = "priceblock_ourprice")
print(original_price)
```

When I run this I get a "NameError: name 'soup' is not defined". I am not sure if it's the fact that the module isn't installed although I know it is because when I printed data it works. Maybe I'm missing something or that statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning to the variable `data`, not `soup`.

Change

```
data = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

and you should be good.

Comment: ah yes I see the issue thanks for the quick reply! :)

Comment: To tack on, you could do `original_price = data.find(id = "priceblock_ourprice")`. At the end of the day it does the same thing.